# Blazor .Net 5 Identity Registration With email confirmation

Tags: email, asp.net-identity, blazor, .net-5

im New in .Net 5 and Blazor , im trying to make registration form with Identity , after i add the pages with scaffolding i want to add email confirmation i tried some example but not passed yet
https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/11/02/using-mailkit-send-receive-email-asp-net-core/

please any idea or example to do this?

```
"EmailConfiguration": {
"SmtpServer": "smtp.gmail.com",
"SmtpPort": 465,
"SmtpUsername": "email@gmail.com",
"SmtpPassword": "password"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved my trouble with MailKit
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/07/15/aspnet-core-3-send-emails-via-smtp-with-mailkit
important notes
to use Gmail as a sender enable Less secure app from email account setting

```
    // create email message
var email = new MimeMessage();
email.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("from_address@example.com"));
email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("to_address@example.com"));
email.Subject = "Test Email Subject";
email.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Plain) { Text = "Example Plain Text Message Body" };

// send email
using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Connect("smtp.ethereal.email", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
smtp.Authenticate("[USERNAME]", "[PASSWORD]");
smtp.Send(email);
smtp.Disconnect(true);
```